# RestSharp proxy http/https/socks information

Tags: c#, proxy, restsharp

I wanted to know what kind of proxies are compatible with RestSharp and how to use them?

Answer (score 2):

You can use System.Net WebProxy as below.

```
var request = new RestRequest(funcName, funcType);
 request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
 request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json";};
 request.AddBody(param);

RestClient restClient = new RestClient(url);
restClient.Proxy = new WebProxy(myProxyUrl,  myProxyHost);
 restClient.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
var value = restClient.Execute(request);
```